# Oracle: SQL query to find all the triggers belonging to the tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

how can i find all the triggers that belong to a table?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The following will work independent of your database privileges:

```
select * from all_triggers
where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'
```

The following alternate options may or may not work depending on your assigned database privileges:

```
select * from DBA_TRIGGERS
```

or

```
select * from USER_TRIGGERS
```

Comment: you may want to add "where table-name = 'FOOBAR'" to that query to narrow your answers down.

Comment: Note: `table_name` should be in _uppercase_.

Answer (score 5):

Check out ALL_TRIGGERS:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2107.htm#i1592586

Answer (score 5):

Another table that is useful is:

```
SELECT * FROM user_objects WHERE object_type='TRIGGER';
```

You can also use this to query views, indexes etc etc

Comment: That should be object_type = **'TRIGGER'** as Oracle is case-sensitive, but ALL_TRIGGERS is better as it also show to which table the trigger belongs (which is not available in ALL_OBJECTS)

Comment: Indeed, I have edited. I was just trying to highlight that the user_objects table was handy for other things.

Comment: You may want to further narrow down your search, by adding: **and object_name like '%foo%';**

Answer (score -6):

Use the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/) and search for keyword "trigger" in your browser.

This approach should work with other metadata type questions.