# Apex: How to find out the schema name?

Tags: oracle-apex

I need to find my schema name because i want to delete triggers which i created. 
For example the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_ORDER
BEFORE INSERT ON HOUSE_ORDER
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.ORDER_ID IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT SEQ_ORDER_ID.NEXTVAL
    INTO :NEW.ORDER_ID FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

When i now try to drop the trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER TRIGGER_ORDER
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-04080: trigger 'TRIGGER_ORDER' does not exist
```

I found out that i need to call something like

```
DROP TRIGGER SCHEMA_NAME.TRIGGER_ORDER
```

but i have no idea what my schema name is. so how can i find it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle : Query to find all the triggers belonging to the tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896621/oracle-query-to-find-all-the-triggers-belonging-to-the-tables)

Comment: How did you even create the trigger? Did you do it through Apex, since you tagged your question with it?

Comment: yes i did create it using a script inside apex

Comment: where di you run the script exactly? I'm asking because you do not know what schema you created it it, though it should be evident.

Comment: What do you mean by "where"? I just logged into apex went to the sql workshop , uploaded a script and executed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [ALL_TRIGGERS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2107.htm#i1592586) view. There's a column named Table Owner which indicates the schema.

```
select * from all_triggers
where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'
```