# Find where a table is being populated?

Tags: oracle, insert, populate

I can't find where a table is being populate in Oracle. The source of the data has to come from somewhere and somehow the data is being inserted. I went through every dependency of the table and did not find an insert statement where data is being added to the table. I even used the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> feature to make sure I was not missing anything.

I also used the following to look for where the data is being populated but had no luck:

```
SELECT *
FROM dba_source
WHERE UPPER(text) LIKE '%MY_TABLE%'
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or tips for what I can do? I've not been in a situation where a table is mysteriously being populated but the procedure cannot be found. I have full rights to see everything, so it has to be somewhere I just haven't found yet.

Please help.

Comment: Is it being populated from a trigger?

Comment: Hopefully you meant `LIKE '%MY_TABLE%'`.  That is, with a trailing percent sign

Comment: @MT0, how would I be able to determine if it is being populated by a trigger?

Comment: @Matthew McPeak, `'%MY_TABLE%'` is acurate. I changed it in the question. However this returns 59 results. it must be populated at only one of them. Is there a way to narrow down the results. I've tried and failed.

Comment: See [Query to find all the triggers belonging to the tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4896621/1509264)