# Is there a way to see triggers code to edit it?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sqlplus

My question is, if i have a trigger created in sqlplus, is there any way to see the code?, or I can only see the information that comes from select * from user_triggers.

Comment: SQLPlus is used with Oracle, not MySQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle: SQL query to find all the triggers belonging to the tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896621/oracle-sql-query-to-find-all-the-triggers-belonging-to-the-tables)

Comment: The thing is that i want to edit the trigger, that only show me the names of the triggers @nbk

Comment: You can use either dbms_metadata as answered by Del or `select text from user_source where type='TRIGGER' and name='&trigger_name'`

Answer (score 3):

First, I want to point out that SQLDeveloper is a free tool you can use to perform a lot of these tasks.  Second, there is a simple query you can run to get the code for a trigger, it is:

```sql
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER', 'TRIGGER_NAME', 'SCHEMA_NAME')
FROM DUAL;
```

Just replace 'TRIGGER_NAME' with the actual name of your trigger.  And 'SCHEMA_NAME' with your schema. The schema name is optional, so you can remove it if you like.

Once you've copied that out into a text editor, you can make changes to your heart's content.  Run it back in either by copying it into SQL*Plus or save it to file and run the file using `@`or `@@`.